# Why is this php time not being subtracted correctly?

Tags: php

Basically, there is a "type" in a database that has "Probation" in it. There is also a time stamp of "2017-01-15 22:18:44" for example in `RealDate`. No matter how long ago the date is, the difference still returns true like it's within three days. Any suggestions?

```
$doR = $totalArr[$i]['RealDate'];
$start = strtotime($doR);
$today = time();
$diff = ($start-$today)/(60 * 60 * 24);
if($diff < 5){
    $parole = "<span style=\"color:red\"> - ON PAROLE</span>";
}
```

Comment: strtotime is not what you seem to think it is .. `/DAY` and DAY is what?

Comment: I thought DAY will tell you how many days. So (time/day)=days... I guess not?

Comment: php has no DAY function, this code should produce erros

Comment: http://ideone.com/vSd9wb PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant DAY - assumed 'DAY' in /home/pkXCIz/prog.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /home/pkXCIz/prog.php on line 3

Comment: Anyone have a proper route I should take?

Comment: supply the number of seconds in a day, or better still use the date\time class:http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: and please develop will full error checking and display ON

Comment: I've looked at the datetime class, and I seem to get overwhelmed. Can you provide me with the code I need? @nogad

Comment: currently only have the time for the quick and dirty: `$diff  = ($start-$today)/(60 * 60 * 24); ` oh then its `if($diff < 3)`...

Comment: See above for updated code. It still returned $parole, and it shouldn't.

Comment: http://ideone.com/kbzNGZ works for me, you need to start echoing every variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're subtracting `$start-$today` when you should be doing it the other way around `$today-$start`

`$start-$today` will always be negative since the time now will always be a larger number than a past time in UNIX timestamp format. Since it's always negative, that's why your condition of `$diff < 5` is always true.

```
$doR = $totalArr[$i]['RealDate'];
$start = strtotime($doR);
$today = time();

// change it like this:
$diff = ($today-$start)/(60 * 60 * 24);

if($diff < 5){
    $parole = "<span style=\"color:red\"> - ON PAROLE</span>";
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I feel for the simple mistake. Thanks a lot! My issue has been fixed.